# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the beginning of my html I've declare my application:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyAppModule">
```

and at the bottom I have include all the necessary files, the Chrome does not complain for any missing file:

```
 <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Controllers/EventController.js"></script>
      <script src="js/Services/EventService.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
```

Here is my application:

```
'use strict';
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var MyAppModule = angular.module('MyAppModule', ['ngResource']).config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/mybooks',{
            templateUrl:'/templates/mybooks.html',
            controller:'EventController'
        }
        );

});
```

But when I am trying to see the page there is a `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyAppModule&p1=Err…js.org%2F1.2.14%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0A%20%20%20...<omitted>...2)` on the browser. Any help? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
['ngResource']
```

With this:

```
['ngResource', 'ngRoute']
```

It looks like you're not injecting the route provider.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I just notice it, silly mistake. Thank you.